# how to get turtlebot pose

Tags: ros, pose, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to get turtlebot poses when it walking. The following codes are used, but there is no responds. I guess it was the problem of topic "/odom". could anybody give me some ideas to fix it?
thanks.

```
virtual void onInit()
{
      ros::NodeHandle& nh = getNodeHandle();
      ros::NodeHandle& private_nh = getPrivateNodeHandle();           
      cmdpub_ = private_nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist> ("cmd_vel", 1);
      sub_= nh.subscribe<PointCloud>("depth/points", 1, &TurtlebotFollower::cloudcb, this);
      ros::Subscriber sub  = nh.subscribe("/odom",10, &TurtlebotFollower::poseCallback,this);
}
    
void poseCallback(const geometry_msgs::TwistPtr& msg){
      std::cout << msg.linear.x << "\t" <<msg.linear.y<< "\t" << 0.0 << "\t" << std::endl;
}
```

I found that if I put above codes into the onInit() virtual function, it will be failed. But if I put it in an main() function, it will be succeed. What is the difference?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217270/how-to-get-turtlebot-pose/) by [baowei lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/23506/baowei-lin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Willson Amalraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/5060/willson-amalraj/) on 2015-09-09**:
Did your poseCallback work even if the message type is geometry_msgs::Twist? You are trying to use nodelets. You have to run them differently. Please follow the link to learn about [running nodelets](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet/Tutorials/Running%20a%20nodelet).

**Comment by [baowei lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/23506/baowei-lin/) on 2015-09-09**:
sorry, the "succeed" means that I've changed them to nav_msgs. I will check nodelets, thank you Willson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed the problem by changing getNodeHandle() to getMTNodeHandle(), which means if you want to subscribe multiple topics, you need a multiple thread callback queue. Thank you Willson again.

---

Originally posted by [baowei lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/23506/baowei-lin/) with karma: 16 on 2015-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the type of "/odom" topic. Use `rostopic type /odom`.
I donot have access to my turtlebot at present. But if I am not wrong, /odom topic is of type nav_msgs/Odometry.

Try the following

```
void poseCallback(const nav_msgs::OdometryConstPtr& msg){  std::cout << msg->pose.pose.position.x << std::endl }
```

---

Originally posted by [Willson Amalraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/5060/willson-amalraj/) with karma: 206 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baowei lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/23506/baowei-lin/) on 2015-09-08**:
Thank you Willson, but I failed based on your code. It seems that poseCallback could not be called. Do I need to configure anywhere else?

**Comment by [Willson Amalraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/5060/willson-amalraj/) on 2015-09-08**:
I cannot comment on that without seeing your TutlebotFollower class. May be you comment out all other subscribers and publishers to check if poseCallback works. (on a side note, instead of using two callbacks you can use message_filters to send messages from two topics to the same callback)